# React Subscribing on a Multicast Response

Tags: reactjs, react-native, race-condition, ssdp

I am implementing an SSDP device discovery app using react-native and react-native-ssdp library. Basically what I am doing is;

Multicasting to network for ssdp devices and listing them on my screen. In order to do the listing;

I have a function that registers on ssdp responses. Each time a response from a device received we are updating the state like `setDeviceList([...deviceList, newDevice]);` But since the devices respond so quick (less than a half of a second), race condition happens and then the update missing real list. In this case I can only see the last device responding in the list.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have used `useState` for the deviceList.
The set-Method of an useState can take a direct parameter or a function where the input parameter is the current value of the state. So you can try something like this:

```js
 const [deviceList, setDeviceList] = useState([])
...
 setDeviceList((currentDeviceList) => [...currentDeviceList, newDevice])
```

Alternatively use something like redux and dispatch every single device to the store. These messages will be queued and you should avoid race conditions.

Comment: After this question post sent. I found the functional update section in react documentation ( wish had seen it before) and did exactly what you suggest. Now it's gone. !